# Вывести направление робота после выполнения полученной команды

Tags: c++

Дана такая задача.

Робот может перемещаться в четырех направлениях («С» — север, «З» — запад, «Ю» — юг, «В» — восток) и принимать три цифровые команды: 0 — продолжать движение, 1 — поворот налево, - 1 — поворот направо. Дан символ C — исходное  направление робота и целое число N — посланная ему команда. Вывести направление робота после выполнения полученной команды.

Программа выдает ошибки на выполнение switch (C). Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

char *Rus(const char *text);

void main()
{
    int N;
    char *C;
    cout << Rus(" Введите направление: ");
    cin >> C;
    cout << Rus(" Введите команду: ");
    cin >> N;
    switch (C) {
    case " с":
        cout << Rus(" направление на север ");
        break;
    case " ю ":
        cout << Rus(" направление на юг ");
        break;
        case " з : cout << Rus(" ? ?аправлениеназапад"); break;
    case " ? ?" : cout << Rus(" ? ?аправлениенавосток"); break;

    }
    switch(N)
    {
    case 0: cout <<  Rus(" ? ?родолжатьдвижение"); break:
    case 1: cout << Rus(" ? ?оворотналево" ); break;
    case -1: cout << Rus(" ? ?оворотнаправо"); break;
    }
    getch();
}
char bufRus[256];
char* Rus(const char* text)
{
    CharToOem(text, bufRus);
    return bufRus;
}
```

Comment: ошибка в том, что в case буквы не читаются, но как сделать чтобы case воспринимал буквы

Comment: Прочитать про оператор switch и типы данных в языке.

--

Вы пишете в case массив (" с" - это массив символов (другими словами char \*)), а switch хочет int (ну, к счастью, char автоматически приводится к int). 

Поэтому напишите 'c' вместо "c". 

Рекомендую для начала русские буковки не использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых ввод указателей - это неправильно, замените char* на string и не забудьте соответствующий include-файл.
Во вторых, как уже сказали, switch работает только с целыми числами, поэтому замените первый switch на if... else if...

Comment: Необязательно так строго.

Можно вводить и слово (символ) в массив символов и делать swith по первому элементу этого массива. 

Для обработки ошибок ввода в switch надо добавить default:

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я так подозреваю, проблема в том, что :
Вы кавычки в третьем *case* забыли
Единичные символы вроде бы в одинарные кавычки помещаются
Вы уверены, что *switch* работает с указателями ?

Comment: там везде в case ковычки, я просто забыл написать, но программа все равно не работает

Comment: @IvAn, прочтите внимательно все комменты - Вам уже ответили

Answer (score 0):

case отлично работает с буквами, в том числе и русскими. Проблема в том, что case не работает со строками. `case " ю ":` - по этой строке никогда не найдет (да, да, это не символ ю, а строка - пробел+ю+пробел). Записывайте это так `case 'ю':` и с большой вероятностью оно почти сразу и заработает.

Comment: Я то прекрасно знаю, что switch с русскими буквами работает. А вот про разные их кодировки TC IMHO понятия не имеет. 

Потом устанете отвечать, почему кракозябры.

Comment: начните с одинарных кавычек

Comment: Дык, нужен костыль `UnRus`, который уравновесит имеющийся костыль `Rus` :-)

Comment: Когда то я мучился с этими костылями для русского языка. А потом перешел на линукс, где, если не перестараться с настройками, одна локаль на все и нет этих проблем.

Comment: теперь, когда программа скомпилировалась, она не показывает направление, которое мы выбрали

Comment: Я думаю, что **это проблема кодировок русских букв** в винде. @IvAn, при вводе надо делать обратное CharToOem(text, bufRus); преобразование OemToChar (почитайте доку). 

То, что сейчас написано в вопросе для ввода начального направления (cin >> С для char *C;), это полная ерунда. C должен быть массивом символов (char C[10])

*Не показывает направление* - это я так понимаю, падает.